# pytorch variable index lost one dimension

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, reshape, pytorch

I am going to get every horizontal tensor in a variable but I got one dimension lost.

This is my code:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
t = torch.rand((2,2,4))
x = Variable(t)
print(x)
shape = x.size()
for i in range(shape[0]):
    for j in range(shape[1]):
        print(x[i,j])
```

and the output is :

```
Variable containing:
(0 ,.,.) =
  0.6717  0.8216  0.5100  0.9106
  0.3280  0.8182  0.5781  0.3919

(1 ,.,.) =
  0.8823  0.4237  0.6620  0.0817
  0.5781  0.4187  0.3769  0.0498
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2x4]

Variable containing:
 0.6717
 0.8216
 0.5100
 0.9106
[torch.FloatTensor of size 4]

Variable containing:
 0.3280
 0.8182
 0.5781
 0.3919
[torch.FloatTensor of size 4]

Variable containing:
 0.8823
 0.4237
 0.6620
 0.0817
[torch.FloatTensor of size 4]

Variable containing:
 0.5781
 0.4187
 0.3769
 0.0498
[torch.FloatTensor of size 4]
```

and how can I get [torch.FloatTensor of size 1x4]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `x` is a 2x2x4 tensor. So when you do `x[0]` you obtain the 2x4 tensor which is in the first row. And if you do `x[i,j]` you obtain the 4 dimensional vector in position (i,j). If you want to retain one of the dimensions you can either use a slice: `x[i,j:j+1]` OR reshape the tensor: `x[i,j].view(1,4)`. Thus your code would look like:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
t = torch.rand((2,2,4))
x = Variable(t)
print(x)
shape = x.size()
for i in range(shape[0]):
    for j in range(shape[1]):
        print(x[i,j:j+1])
```

or

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
t = torch.rand((2,2,4))
x = Variable(t)
print(x)
shape = x.size()
for i in range(shape[0]):
    for j in range(shape[1]):
        print(x[i,j].view(1,4)
```

Will give you the desired result.

**Edit:**

Yes, or as mentioned in the answer by nnnmmm,  `torch.unsqueeze(x[i, j], 0)` also works as it adds a dimension of size 1 in the 0th position.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`torch.unsqueeze(x[i, j], 0)`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze).

Comment: Thank you for you reply and it is useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add the desired dimension with `None` afterwards

```
x[:, j][:, None]
```

but you can even go for including it in the indexing in the first place

```
x[:, j, None]
```